# Is there any way to avoid nested properties in sequlize relations?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

If you make this sequelize query:

```
await this.myModel.findAll({
      attributes: [
        'someAttribute'
      ]
      include: [anotherModel]
    })
```

You get a result like this:

```
{
   "someAttribute": "some data",
   "anotherrModel": {
     "attributesFromAnotherModel": "some data"
   }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?
I know i could modify this in Js, but the point here is make it with sequelize to avoid the need to make the request and then mutate the object.
So the object that I'm thinking look like this:

```
{
   "someAttribute": "some data",
   "attributesFromAnotherModel": "some data"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that nothing prevents two actual database tables from having common column names; for example, it's really common for tables to have an "id" column, or "something_id" columns for foreign keys. A JavaScript object can have only one value for a given property name.

Comment: Seems like you need something like `attributes: { include: [[Sequelize.col('anotherModel.attributesFromAnotherModel', 'attributesFromAnotherModel')]]}`

Comment: @Pointy So that can lead to an issue, I understand, so what options do I have?

Comment: @Anatoly And how do I add the attribute from "myModel" I mean the first model

Comment: You could bypass sequelize and just write a regular SQL JOIN query. sequelize is trying to do better by returning a result that represents the relationship explicitly and unambiguously.

Comment: You can just list all main model attributes and add this special one (using an array instead of an object with `include` option)